# ConfigurationProperties outside of spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to make us of @ConfigurationProperties behaviour for a non-Spring Boot application? To explain a bit clearer, I've a library module that in future I would like to use in a non-spring boot environment so I wondered if ConfigurationProperties could be utilised without bringing in a large bunch of spring-boot core dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need spring-boot-stater to pull in the configuration, so I guess no is the answer :D